# Read columns from file into separate variables

Tags: bash, command-line, text-processing

I need to read the following input into separate columns as variables?
input.txt

```
b73_chr10   w22_chr9
w22_chr7    w22_chr10
w22_chr8    w22_chr6
```

I have written the following command;but I guess it is not correct.

```
value1=$(echo $line| awk -F\ '{print $1}' input.txt)
value2=$(echo $line| awk -F\ '{print $2}' input.txt)
```

Comment: Why are you setting the field separator to a value (`;`) that doesn't present in your input file?

Comment: Okk..I will edit it.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use the `read` shell builtin:

```
while IFS=" " read -r value1 value2 remainder
do
    ...
done < "input.txt"
```

Extra fields, if any, will appear in 'remainder'.  The shell's default `IFS` (inter-field-seperator) consisting of white space characters will be used to split each line into its component fields.

Comment: How to provide the file name in this syntax ? Like the filename(for e.g input.txt) in this syntax ?

Comment: I've added input redirection to provide the name of the file to be read.

Comment: I have another query..if you dont mind.I added this condition inside the loop:
sed 's/$value1/$value2/g' circos.conf

Is it correct to work ?