# How to loop a command through a file column values?

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing

I have a simple command like this

```
 grep 'X' results.dat | awk '{print $NF}'  > Y.dat
```

I want to loop this command taking the **Xs** from **column 1** and the corresponding **Ys** from **column 2** of the same file **eg. NAMES**

NAMES file has the format

```
C11-C12     p01
C13-C14-C17 P02
etc ..
```

so the first two steps in the loop should be like this

```
grep 'C11-C12' results.dat | awk '{print $NF}'  > p01.dat
grep 'C13-C14-C17' results.dat | awk '{print $NF}'  > p02.dat
```

Comment: Show your input and desired output.

Comment: A wild guess: `awk '$1 ~ /X/{print $1, $2}'  results.dat`

Comment: What are you going to do with the `p01.dat` and `p02.dat` files?  I give 24 to 1 odds that there is a better way to accomplish your *final* end result without making these intermediate files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution that doesn’t require looping in the shell:

```
awk 'pass==1 {  Xpatt[NR] = $1; Yfile[NR] = $2 ".dat"; printf "" > Yfile[NR] }
     pass==2 {
                for (i in Xpatt) {
                        if ($0 ~ Xpatt[i]) print $NF > Yfile[i]
                }
             }' pass=1 NAMES pass=2 results.dat
```

- First of all,
  `awk` allows you to specify variable assignments as command-line arguments,
  after the program, mixed in with the filenames, and not using `-v`. 
  They are executed at the point in the processing sequence
  that their position in the command line would suggest.
  So, in the above command,

  1. `pass` gets set to 1,
  2. the `NAMES` file is processed,
  3. `pass` gets set to 2, and then
  4. the `results.dat` file is processed.

  I guess I could have set `pass=1` with a `-v` or in a `BEGIN` block.

  I use the `pass` variable to tell which file I’m reading. 
  This is commonly done by comparing `NR` to `FNR`,
  but that can lead to false indications if a file is empty.

  (Strictly speaking,
  I suppose that this script should check whether either of the files is empty,
  because, in that case, there’s no work to be done.)
- While `pass==1` (we’re reading the `NAMES` file),
  save the X and Y values (pattern and filename)
  from columns 1 and 2 (`$1` and `$2`) of that file. 
  Create the output file (`Yfile[NR]`) because,
  if we don’t do it here, we will not get (empty) output files
  for patterns that are not present in the `results.dat` file. 
  (If that’s OK with you, leave out the `printf` statement.)
- While `pass==2` (we’re reading the `results.dat` file),
  loop through the patterns in the `NAMES` file
  and print the last word from every line that matches the pattern
  into the corresponding file — i.e., the equivalent
  of the OP’s `grep X … | awk '{print $NF}'  > Y.dat` command.

Comment: Interesting edge case re: empty files and `FNR == NR`.  Upvoted just for that.

Answer (score 1):

Bash solution:

```
while read X Y remainder || [[ -n ${Y} ]]; do
    awk -v X="$X" '$0 ~ $X {print $NF}' results.dat > "$Y".dat
done < NAMES
```

- Generally, `while IFS="q" read X Y remainder; do ...; done < NAMES` will iterate over lines from `NAMES`. It will separate the values in each line based on the value of `IFS` (internal field separator). In this example, `IFS` is set to the letter `q`. `IFS` defaults to whitespace (space characters, tabs, or newlines). The first field is assigned the variable `X`, the second to `Y`, and the rest of the line to `remainder`.

  See also: [Read columns from file into separate variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/260841/37941) (Unix.SE).

  In the solution above, `IFS` is not specified because I **assume** your fields are already whitespace-separated.

  Note: if the fields in your `NAMES` file contains backslashes, then you need to use `read -r` to prevent `read` from interpreting backslashes as escape sequences.
- The `... remainder || [[ -n ${remainder} ]]` part handles two things: any extra fields, if any, are stored in `remainder`; and handles the case if the last line of your input file doesn't end with newline `\n` (`read` returns a non-zero exit code when it encounters EOF).

  See also: [Read a file line by line assigning the value to a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10929511/1123413) (SO).
- Eliminate `grep` altogether: `awk -v X="$X" '$0 ~ $X {print $NF}' results.dat > "$Y".dat`. The `-v` option to `awk` defines a variable that can be used in the `awk` script.

Comment: [Using a shell loop to process text is a bad idea.](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/135943)  But, good for explaining the parts.

Comment: @Wildcard generally agreed. However, in this case the OP is asking how to use lines and fields from _one_ file to process _another_. In this case, an `awk` one-liner is probably less readable. Especially when you consider that OP's original approach was `grep pattern | awk '{print $NF}'`, which indicates to me a low level of facility with `awk` to begin with.

Comment: Agreed on the low facility with Awk—but even then, the answer is to [explain yourself well](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/327402/135943), not to dumb down the answer and give a worse approach to solving the problem than you are capable of.

Comment: @Wildcard In truth and fairness, I didn't dumb down the answer, because the approach I gave is my best tradeoff between readability and my own facility with the tools.

Comment: Ah, gotcha.  In that case, I highly recommend reading the linked answer (re shell loops) in full and then revisiting this answer to see how you can improve it.  :)

Comment: (1) You should always quote your shell variable references (e.g., `"$X"`, `"$Y"` and `"$remainder"`) unless you have a good reason not to, and you’re sure you know what you’re doing.  Putting them into curly braces isn’t nearly as useful as some people seem to think; see [this](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/32210/80216#286525 "Question titled “using single or double bracket – bash”").  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (2) For completeness, you might want to mention that, if the X and Y values might contain backslashes, the user should use `read -r`.  (3) I understand the bit about the last line of a file not ending with newline, but why are you saying `-n ${remainder}`?  It seems like `-n "$X"` would be more appropriate.  (4) You forgot to include `results.dat` on your `awk` command.

Comment: @G-Man (1) Indeed, thank you. (2) Yeah, I originally left it out because I made the assumption OP's data didn't have backslashes, but you're right, there's no reason to omit that. (3) Again, oops. But the correct check is if _Y_ is not null/empty. As long as we parsed a pair of fields, the line is valid. If the check was `-n ${X}`, it would possibly parse and accept a non-newline-terminated line at the end with only one field. (4) Again, oops, and thank you. Big derp there. =)

Comment: @scottbb: Oh, another thing that I didn't notice until I wrote my own answer: `$0 ~ $X` should be `$0 ~ X`.