# How to print multiple values from a file?

Tags: ping

```
#!/bin/bash
COUNT=100
SIZE=100
INTERVAL=0.2
for myHost in `cat /files0/home/singhtr/input`
do
    echo $myHost

    ping -i $INTERVAL -q -n -s  $SIZE -c $COUNT $myHost|grep -i packet

done
```

The input file:

```
# cat input
4.2.2.2 abc ATT
8.8.8.8 def BCC
```

How can I print multiple values from input file like this

Expected Output:

```
IP of the device: 4.2.2.2
Device Name: abc
customer name:ATT
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
```

and so on as the loop goes.

I want to achieve this through bash/shell script.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read columns from file into separate variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/260840/read-columns-from-file-into-separate-variables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
while read myHost
do
    COUNT=100
    SIZE=100
    INTERVAL=0.2
    IP=$(echo $myHost | cut -d " " -f1)
    NAME=$(echo $myHost | cut -d " " -f2)
    CUSTOMER=$(echo $myHost | cut -d " " -f3)
    PING=$(ping -i $INTERVAL -q -n -s  $SIZE -c $COUNT $IP | grep -i packet)
    echo "IP of the device: $IP"
    echo "Device name: $NAME"
    echo "Customer name: $CUSTOMER"
    echo "$PING"
    echo ""
done < /files0/home/singhtr/input
```

This is one possible solution to your Problem. You can just use `cut` to select the `field` you want to output. And then output it with a simple `echo` command.
To read in a file a single line at a time you can use

```
while read LINE
do
 ...
done < FILE
```

*EDIT*

If you want to run a script on a regular basis you should consider creating a `cronjob`. You can type  `crontab -l` to see the `cronjobs` of the current logged-in user. If you want to schedule a `cronjob` you can do as follows:

```
$ crontab -e
```

edit the crontab by inserting for example:

```
*/15 * * * * /path/to/script >> /path/to/log_\`date +%s\` 2>&1
```

This will create a `cronjob` that runs the script at the location `/path/to/script` every 15 minutes and write it output + errors that might occur to file located at `/path/to/log_` with a suffix of a unix time stamp (for example 1549883612).

Comment: can you please share the sample code to run this script in let's say every 15 minutes and save the output to a file in same directory with name segregated by time value or any number.

Answer (score 0):

Er... you need to get a grip on some details of Bash. :-) Right now you're off by a few hundred yards.

This should help you get going:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo ----- reading one field at a time
for myhost in `cat ips`
do
        echo $myhost
done

echo
echo ----- reading and printing one line at a time

while read line
do
        echo $line
done < ips

echo ----- separating fields
while read line
do
        ip=$( cut -d' ' -f1 <<< "$line" )
        dev=$( cut -d' ' -f2 <<< "$line" )
        cust=$( cut -d' ' -f3 <<< "$line" )

        echo IP of device: $ip
        echo device name: $dev
        echo customer name: $cust

        #do your ping here
        echo
done < ips
```

relevant details can be found in:

> $ man cut
>
> $ man bash -> section "SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS", subsection about the
>   command read

and about the "<<<":

> $ man bash -> section "Here Strings"

or use echo $line ... instead of the here string (<<<)

> echo $line | cut -d' ' -f1 etc